# Conditional sum and count in Teradata (SQL help)

Tags: sql, teradata

My data is setup in the following way:

```
Person  Account Revenue Region
    A       W       100     AU
    A       W       200     AU
    A       W       300     AU
    B       X       200     AU
    B       X       50      CH
    B       X       50      CH
```

Here is code for the sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#StackTest') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #StackTest;

CREATE TABLE #StackTest
(Person varchar(1)
, Account varchar(1)
, Revenue int
, Region varchar(2));

INSERT INTO #StackTest
(Person
, Account
, Revenue
, Region)
VALUES
('A', 'W', 100, 'AU'),
('A', 'W', 200, 'AU'),
('A', 'W', 300, 'AU'),
('B', 'X', 200, 'AU'),
('B', 'X', 50, 'CH'),
('B', 'X', 50, 'CH');
```

I need to write a SQL query that sums revenue for only those accounts when total sum of an account Q exceeds Y. Similarly, I also need to count only those accounts when total sum of an account Q exceeds Y. So if my sum threshold for region AU is 500 and for region CH is 200, then I would want the following output

```
Output  # of accounts exceeding threshold sum   Revenue from these accounts 
A                     1                                  600    
B                     0                                   0
```

However, my current query is checking each line item separately and not at the account level.

What should I do?

Comment: Where's your query?  Is it MySQL or SQL Server?  Can't be both.  Please tag properly.

Comment: Where is threshold information stored?

Comment: The threshold information has to be added as a condition in the query.

Comment: Why is `# of accounts > threshold`?   Three accounts combine exceed the threshold.

Comment: You will still have tell us which RDBMS you are using. The implementation of this logic in MySQL may be very different then it would be in SQL Server where one is able to make use of Window Functions to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

In standard SQL, you would use two levels of aggregation.  I suspect that the query is something like:

```
select person,
       sum(case when region = 'AU' and revenue > 500 then 1
                when region = 'CH' and revenue > 200 then 1
                else 0
           end) as numAccounts,
       sum(case when region = 'AU' and revenue > 500 then revenue
                when region = 'CH' and revenue > 200 then revenue
                else 0
           end) as reveue,
from (select person, region, sum(revenue) as revenue
      from t
      group by person, region
     ) t
group by person;
```

Comment: I want threshold to be applied to account level sum for each person and then for the output show the person, sum of revenue from accounts exceeding threshold sum, and count of those accounts

Answer (score 1):

The following query will aggregate by person/region, and then apply regional thresholds from separate table in order to generate results.

**Updated to account for separate regional thresholds**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Thresholds') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Thresholds
CREATE TABLE #Thresholds (Region VARCHAR(2), Revenue INT)
INSERT #Thresholds VALUES ('AU', 500), ('CH', 200)

--DECLARE @Threshold INT = 500
SELECT
    T.Person,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.[Revenue] >= Thresholds.Revenue THEN T.[Count] ELSE 0 END) AS [# of accounts exceeding threshold sum],
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.[Revenue] >= Thresholds.Revenue THEN T.[Revenue] ELSE 0 END) AS [Revenue from these accounts]
FROM (
    SELECT
        Person,
        Region, -- Add region to apply thresholds by region
        COUNT(DISTINCT Account) AS [Count],
        SUM(Revenue) AS [Revenue]
    FROM #StackTest
    GROUP BY Person, Region
) T
    INNER JOIN #Thresholds Thresholds
        ON Thresholds.Region = T.Region
GROUP BY Person
ORDER BY Person
```

Comment: What about different thresholds for different geographies? E.g. 500 for AU, 200 for CH? How do I take care of that?

Comment: Depends on where the thresholds come. I would just join the "T" table against the region threshold table to replace the @Threshold variable. I'll update answer with example of what i mean

Comment: Updated. Hope that helps!